# Accessing a cell value in Pandas DataFrame - nsepy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quandl, nsepy

Can someone please help me to understand the structure of the data frame I am receiving from a function call and also share how can I access a particular cell value in that data frame?

Following is the output when I print `resultData.shape`

```
(0, 14)

(22, 14)
```

Following is the output when I print `resultData`

```
(0, 14)

Empty DataFrame

Columns: [Symbol, Series, Prev Close, Open, High, Low, Last, Close, VWAP, Volume, Turnover, Trades, Deliverable Volume, %Deliverble]

Index: []
(22, 14)

             Symbol Series  Prev Close     Open     High      Low     Last  \
Date                                                                       
2018-01-01    ACC     EQ     1758.40  1763.95  1763.95  1725.00  1731.40   
2018-01-02    ACC     EQ     1731.35  1736.20  1745.80  1725.00  1739.00   
2018-01-03    ACC     EQ     1743.20  1741.10  1780.00  1740.10  1780.00   
2018-01-04    ACC     EQ     1774.60  1779.95  1808.00  1770.00  1794.50
```

I need to access 'Open' price on 2018-01-01.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the output of `type(resultData)`?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe indicated has index of data type datatime.date and columns as represented [Symbol, Series, Prev Close, Open, High, Low, Last, Close, VWAP, Volume, Turnover, Trades, Deliverable Volume, %Deliverble]

to Access the "Open" value for the date 2018-01-01,
use the below statement

Format:
dataframe.loc[row, column]

resultData.loc[date(2018,1,1),'Open']